# Wordpress customize sidebar customize.php of a theme

Tags: php, css, wordpress

im newbie using wordpress themes. Im working on a wordpress theme named customizr theme. I want to change the themes sidebar customize.php [This sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7Crk.jpg).

I want to change its color or skin and add more functionalities inside. Is there a way where i can do this?

Like some reference guide to let me know on how to achieve this one or maybe some code which i can use and insert into its functions.php. Im using the customizr theme version 3.3.20.

Comment: Its Better to ask this question at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks for redirecting me